# response.pipe(file) throws error on Windows Server | Works fine on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to download a file and move it to a specific folder. It works fine on my local Linux machine but throws an error when executed on Windows Server:

[image: Error on Windows Server]

```js
router.post('/pullDraftFile', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.reference && !req.query.draftFileId) {
        return res.sendStatus(502);
    }
    const reference = req.query.reference;
    const fileUrl = `${s3DraftBucketURL}${req.query.draftFileId}`;

    http.get(fileUrl, function (response) {

        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const contentDisposition = response.headers['content-disposition'];
            console.log(response.headers['content-type']);
            resolve(contentDisposition && /^attachment/i.test(contentDisposition) ?
                req.query.draftFileId + '|' + contentDisposition.substring(contentDisposition.indexOf('=') + 1, contentDisposition.length) : req.query.draftFileId + '|');
        }).then((fileName) => {
            if (!fs.existsSync(`${watchFolders}/${reference}`)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(`${watchFolders}/${reference}`);
            }
            const downloadedFile = `downloads/${fileName}`;
            const watchFile = `${watchFolders}/${reference}/${fileName}`;
            const file = fs.createWriteStream(downloadedFile);
            var stream = response.pipe(file);
            stream.on('finish', () => {
                console.log('File Download Successfully');
                fs.rename(downloadedFile, watchFile, function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    console.log('File Moved Successfully!');
                });
            });
        });
    });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the separator from '|' to ','.